# Array.Find with Delegate. What does it return if not found?

Tags: c#, arrays, delegates, find

I have an `Array<Person> myArray` and I am using the following code

```
myArray.Find(o => o.name.Equals("John"));
```

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) in Msdn states:

> Return Value
>
> Type: T
>
> The first element that matches the conditions defined by the
>   specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type T.

If I had an `Array<int>` the default value would be zero.
But, in my case I am using a class. Let's say `Array<Person>`.

What would be the default for my class and how can I handle the not found case using a delegate?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default for any reference type (class, interface, delegate) is a null reference. The default for any value type is a value where all the fields of the type are the default value for that field - so you end up with 0, `\0`, false etc.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming Person is a reference type, the default value for it would be null.

Therefore the call to Array.Find() would return null when the condition wasn't satisfied.